# SQL Server stored procedure - return flight numbers

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I was trying to write a SQL Server stored procedure that would return a list of my flight numbers and based on the price would rate the flight as followed:
price <= 500 as Cheap, price >500 and price >=1500 as Normal or else as Expensive

I have tried this but I feel like I'm way off:

```
create procedure rate_flights
    @result varchar(50) output
as
    declare @fno varchar(100)
    declare @price numeric(10,2)
begin
    set @fno = (select fno from flights)
    set @price = (select price from flights)
    set @result = (select case
                            when @price <= 500 then @fno + ' '+'Φθηνή'
                            when @price > 501 and @price < 1500 then @fno + ' '+ 'Κανονική'
                            when @price > 1500 then @fno + ' ' + 'Ακριβή'
                          end)
end

declare @ret varchar(50)
execute rate_flights @result = @ret out
print @ret
```

If anyone could point me to the right direction, I would appreciate it.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What do you mean? if you want to get a list, you need to do "select case when....from..." and not return one result. however, the statement "set @fno = (select fno from flights)" got you given you the first result at randomize order.

Comment: Please edit the title of your question to mean something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the variables (single values) from a select, so you get only the first result for @price and @fno

You should do the calculation at the same time than the select; and probably you don't want to return a varchar but a table.

Start thinking on sets / tables, not standard data types variables; you may use CTEs or table variables if you want, but for SQL databases, you need an alternative programming paradigm

My general suggestion would be something like:

```
create procedure rate_flights
as
begin
    select fno, price,
    case
      when @price <= 500 then @fno + ' '+'Φθηνή'
      when @price > 501 and @price < 1500 then @fno + ' '+ 'Κανονική'
      when @price > 1500 then @fno + ' ' + 'Ακριβή' 
    end as rate

 from flights

end
```

Comment: thank you for replying to be completely honest i didn't know you could use select case this way that would have made things easier :D

Answer (score 2):

Case statement could be reduce even more like this

```
  case 
        when price  <= 500 then 'Cheap'
        when price <=1500 then 'Normal'
        else 'Expensive'
    end as Rating
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Ya gotta love the top-down processing order of CASE.  Makes some really nice short and easy to read code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are over complicating it, and you aren't returning the entire list. Instead, you need a simple select with your case statement.

```
create procedure rate_flights
as
select 
    fno,
    case 
        when price  <= 500 then 'Cheap'
        when price >500 and price <=1500 then 'Normal'
        else 'Expensive'
    end as Rating
from flights
```

Comment: wow, that was way easier than i thought thank you very much for your answer

Comment: No problem @Sakis